# Determine location of Smart-LOB (Informix 11.5)

Tags: informix

How, in Informix IDS 11.5, do I determine in which SmartLob space does a BLOB reside?

So really it's two questions:

1. How can I get something like the dbschema command to produce the PUT clause.
2. How can I find from which sblobspace did a particular SmartLOB come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the DB-Schema (first) question is "with the '`-ss`' option", where '`ss`' is mnemonic for 'server-specific'.  This will include the data specific to IDS, such as the PUT clause.

The counter-question for the blobspace (second) question is:

- Why do you think it matters which blobspace the blob comes from?

For an individual smart blob, you can find out which blob space a specific smart blob is stored in as long as you are using ESQL/C or one of the related C-based APIs.  The function to do this is `ifx_lo_specget_sbspace()`, and it is documented in the ESQL/C manual.

I don't know of an SQL-based way of determining the smart blobspace that holds a particular blob.

Comment: I'm not sure that it matters to me; but can't the table be altered to start putting blobs in a different space?  I really asked in anticipation of questions from my employer.

Comment: Yes, the table can be altered to put blobs in different smart blob spaces.

Comment: Wanted to add we recently installed this (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/zones/informix/library/techarticle/db_sblob.html#SblobSbspace) module and it'll tell you where a blob resides.